# how to give virtual machine local IP?

Tags: windows

I want to ping to my main pc so I want to make my virtual machine address local my mean pc address is 192.168.1.1 ,but my virtual machine address is 127.1.0.1

I use windows 10 and the system of the virtual machine is linux ubuntu .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open your virtual machine click on **Devices** from the menu above then **network** then **network settings** then you need to change "**attached to**" to **Bridged Adapter** then **OK** .